# How do I compute an array of mins in Excel?

Tags: excel

Lets say my data has a column of numbers in A. I want the sum of A unless the number in A is greater than some threshold. Conceptually I want `SUM(MIN(A:A, 1000))`, but this will return just the single smallest number.

In R there is pmin, which is a parallel minima, so I could write `SUM(PMIN(A:A, 1000))` and each value in A is compared against 1000.

In Excel, I could create a new column B that was `MIN(A1,1000)` and drag it down. But I don't want to create a new column. I want to compute the sum in a single equation. Any solution?

Comment: You can use `sumif()` for this: `=SUMIF(A:A, "<1000",A:A )`

Comment: `=SUMIF(A:A, "<=1000") + 1000 * COUNTIF(A:A, ">1000")`

Comment: Make that an answer, @brittenb. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to make a new column, you'll need to do it in two parts. The first part sums all of the values that are less than or equal to 1,000, while the second part adds 1,000 for each value that is over that value. It should be obvious that you would just replace 1,000 with whatever threshold you'd like to impose. Here is the code:

`SUMIF(A:A, "<=1000") + 1000 * COUNTIF(A:A ">1000")`